# How to select most recent file based off of date in filename

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a list of files

```
- backups/
  - backup.2017-08-28.zip
  - backup.2017-08-29.zip
  - backup.2017-09-2.zip
```

I would like to be able to upload the most recent back to a server which I can do with command:

`dobackup ~/backups/backup.2017-09-2.zip`

**My questions is:** Within a `.sh` file (so I can start an automated/cron job for this) how can I get the latest file name to then run that command?

**Limitation:** I must use the date on the filename not the modifcation metadata.

Comment: to make the task a bit easier you may want to update/modify the job that creates the files to make sure it always uses a 2-digit value for day (like it's already doing for month), eg, so instead of `backup.2017-09-2.zip` you'd have `backup.2017-09-02.zip`; then you could (obviously) rely on `ls` and/or `sort` to get the most recent file based on the datestamp in the filename

Comment: I'm not sure I can. But if I'm using regex (I've no idea if that is possible but if it is) it would just be ~~.[0-9]+.zip right?

Comment: Something like "ls -tr backups | tail -1"

Comment: @gile as stated in the limitation I can't base it off of the modification date.

Comment: You are right, so, if you use 2-digits for days and month, as @markp suggested, something like ""ls backups | tail -1" should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a couple more files:

```
backup.2017-08-28.zip
backup.2017-08-29.zip
backup.2017-09-10.zip
backup.2017-09-2.zip
backup.2017-09-28.zip
backup.2017-09-3.zip
```

How about something like this, though granted, a bit convoluted:

```
ls -1 backup*zip | sed 's/-\([1-9]\)\./-0\1\./g' | sort [-r] | sed 's/-0\([1-9]\)\./-\1\./g'
```

- `sed` is looking for a match like `-[0-9].`
- the escaped/matching parens - `\(` and `\)` designates a pattern we want to reference in the replacement portion
- the new pattern will be `-0\1.` where the `\1` is a reference to the first pattern wrapped in escaped/matching parens (ie, `\1` will be replaced with the single digit that matched `[0-9]`)
- our period (`.`) is escaped to make sure it's handled as a literal period and not considered as a single-position wildcard
- at this point the `ls/sed` construct has produced a list of files with 2-digit days
- we run through `sort` (or `sort -r`) as needed
- then run the results back through `sed` to convert back to a single digit day for days starting with a `0`
- at this point you can use a `head` or `tail` to strip off the first/last line based on which `sort`/`sort -r` you used

Running against the sample files:

```
$ ls -1 backup*zip | sed 's/-\([1-9]\)\./-0\1\./g' | sort | sed 's/-0\([1-9]\)\./-\1\./g'

backup.2017-08-28.zip
backup.2017-08-29.zip
backup.2017-09-2.zip
backup.2017-09-3.zip
backup.2017-09-10.zip
backup.2017-09-28.zip

# reverse the ordering
$ ls -1 backup*zip | sed 's/-\([1-9]\)\./-0\1\./g' | sort -r | sed 's/-0\([1-9]\)\./-\1\./g'

backup.2017-09-28.zip
backup.2017-09-10.zip
backup.2017-09-3.zip
backup.2017-09-2.zip
backup.2017-08-29.zip
backup.2017-08-28.zip
```

Comment: Ah perfect, I added `| head -1` to the end and it does the trick

Comment: yeah, figured you'd figure that out; I wanted to show all files sorted properly; going to add a couple more file names to show ordering ... done; answer has been updated

Answer (score 2):

You can sort it on 2nd field delimited by dot:

```
printf '%s\n' backup.* | sort -t '.' -k2,2r | head -1

backup.2017-09-2.zip
```

Comment: Thanks for this would you mind explaining how this works ie the `-k2,2r` ?

Comment: Did you test with `backup.2017-09-2 backup.2017-09-10 ` ?

Comment: Ah yes, `backup.2017-09-2` should be converted to `backup.2017-09-02`  to get the sorting right.